# Modify linq query how to?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

How can i shorter below codes than before? 
i need short  and simple method: 
i dont want to use foreach loop because i have one value.

```
  public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        StaffManagementEntities staffContext;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadStaffPersonel();
            }
        }

        void LoadStaffPersonel()
        {
            int selectedDepartman = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["SelectedDepartmanID"]);
            string name="";
            using (staffContext = new StaffManagementEntities())
            {

                var DepartmanName = from d in staffContext.Departman
                                    where d.ID == selectedDepartman
                                    select d;
                foreach (Departman d in DepartmanName)
                {
                    name = d.Name;
                }

                ObjectResult<StaffsPersonel> personalData = staffContext.GetPersonelData(name);
                gvPersonel.DataSource = personalData;
                gvPersonel.DataBind();

            }
        }

    }
```

How to use string value instead of " var DepartmanName "

Comment: added the tag linq-to-entities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
string name = (from d in staffContext.Departman
               where d.ID == selectedDepartman
               select d.Name).First();
```

or:

```
string name = staffContext.Departman.Where(d=>d.ID == selectedDepartman)
                  .First().Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
string name = (from d in staffContext.Departman
                                where d.ID == selectedDepartman
                                select d.Name).SingleOrDefault();
```

The **SingleOrDefault** will return the name or null if the department does not exit.

**Update:**

- Seems like you at the moment need to use the **First** method as **ykaratoprak** commented. But according to [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/05/18/sneak-preview-entity-framework-4-0-testability-improvements.aspx) the Single/SingleOrDefault will be added in Entity Framework 4.0.

Comment: you are in error: 'The method 'Single' is not supported by LINQ to Entities. Consider using the method 'First' instead.'

Comment: @ykaratoprak - that is a bit harsh; you didn't make it obvious that you were using EF. This answer would be fine with many LINQ providers, such as LINQ-to-SQL. I'm giving it +1...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "FirstOrDefault" which is available in the current 3.5 framework.  I think it may have been included with 3.0, but I'm not certain.  I think it will return null (as opposed to an empty string) if the item isn't found....but you'll want to double check that.

string name = (from d in staffContext.Departman
                                where d.ID == selectedDepartman
                                select d.Name).FirstOrDefault();